# Display related posts based on custom meta field on single WordPress post page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a website for a DJ friend of mine who uploads his mixes to Soundcloud to share, he will also be using his website to post his mixes (via Soundcloud) and to post events.

To handle the events side of things, rather than using a custom post type, I simply added my own meta fields to the standard post screen, and set-up the posts to display the event info if it is set, and display the posts normally if not. [Full code](http://pastebin.com/2UDjBjCU), relevant part:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$event_venue = get_post_meta($postid, 'event_venue', true);
```

In addition to this, to handle his mixes, I have set up a custom post type (generally to make it easier for him to distinguish, as he's not terribly techsavvy outside of a mixer and turntables) and custom meta fields to allow him to add where the mix was recorded (venue-wise) and his soundcloud URL to the mix (which is used to automatically embed the mix in the post, rather than using a plugin). I have created a custom loop and `single-mixes.php` page to handle the display of the data, which is essentially the original loop (renamed to `loop-mixes.php` so I know what's what) but includes a file `mix_data.php`. [Full code](http://pastebin.com/JgPrrBP2), relevant part:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$mix_venue = get_post_meta($postid, 'mix_venue', true);
```

Now, my question. I would like, in the single post page, to compare the data held in `$mix_venue` with every other post that has `$event_venue` set, and display those posts which are a match (i.e, so if a user is viewing a mix, they can then see any upcoming events (and, indeed, any past events) held in the venue in which it was recorded).

**But**, I'm teaching myself WordPress as I go, and I'm really not entirely sure where to begin with this one.

Comment: Edit: 
The test mix post is here: http://djryanmcnally.flyfx.co.uk/mixes/text-mix-one/

I would like to show related posts below the soundcloud player :)

You may notice in mix_data.php I have echoed $mix_url beside the clock icon in the coundcloud player, that was me testing the correct output, I just haven't edited that bit out yet :)

Comment: **Solved it :)** For anyone else with this query, I used a new query inside my loop-mixes.php to display it, as follows;
 

http://pastebin.com/u0uGeaF0




**Note**, i've only put the titles in for now, because i've literally just solved it, gonna go format it all nicely now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you solved it, but I'll suggest a re-usable approach.

In your theme's `functions.php` put this function ([full arguments list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for `get_posts()`):

```
function print_event_venues( $mix_venue )
{   
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'event_venue', 
        'meta_value' => $mix_venue
        );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    // DO NOTHING
    if( !$posts )
        return;

    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        // DO YOUR HTML
        echo $post->post_title;
    }
}
```

Then, in any template, simply call it: `print_event_venues( $the_mix_venue );`.

Useful info: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615).

Comment: Thanks! That'll be handy for some later ideas :)

One other query, in my main loop (for the blog page) as I said, I include a file that checks that meta-fields for the event details are set, and shows the details if they are, however, in the new query i've created, when I include that file (the first pastebin in my original post), nothing shows, despite the details obviously being set (otherwise the query wouldn't find them! Am I missing something? :/

Comment: Are you doing a query inside a query? If so, try the `function` approach. Use this to inspect variables: `echo '<!-- <pre>' . print_r($var, true) . '</pre> -->';`. And if you are doing a question inside a question, open a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ;)

Comment: Oh, yes, having to go to an external site to see the code is not good. Try to make the Questions self-contained. And more concise too, I found difficult to follow all the explanation you gave, context is good but, IMO, it was too much...

Comment: I was being silly, I used $postid instead of get_the_id() when I was fetching the meta values for the related posts. Silly me :)

My bad for not starting a new question! Soz!

Comment: No prob, glad you got it sorted out!